# QSystemTrayIcon notification message with custom icon

Tags: qt, qt5, system-tray

QSystemTrayIcon has a function :

```
void showMessage(const QString &title, const QString &msg,
                     MessageIcon icon = Information, int msecs = 10000);
```

**is there a way to change it to custom icon , for example like this -**

```
void showIconMessage(const QString &title, const QString &msg,
                     QIcon icon = QIcon(), int msecs = 10000);
```

**without modifying the Qt sources**

I know that `showMessage` (d is instance of QSystemTrayIconPrivate and is called with `Q_D(QSystemTrayIcon)` macro)

```
void QSystemTrayIcon::showMessage(const QString& title, const QString& msg,
                            QSystemTrayIcon::MessageIcon icon, int msecs)
{
    Q_D(QSystemTrayIcon);
    if (d->visible)
        d->showMessage_sys(title, msg, icon, msecs);
}
```

calls `showMessage_sys` from `QSystemTrayIconPrivate` where in turn all the magic with icon happens:

```
void QSystemTrayIconPrivate::showMessage_sys(const QString &message,
                                             const QString &title,
                                             QSystemTrayIcon::MessageIcon icon,
                                             int msecs)
{
    if (!qpa_sys)
        return;

    QIcon notificationIcon;
    switch (icon) {
    case QSystemTrayIcon::Information:
        notificationIcon = QApplication::style()-   >standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MessageBoxInformation);
        break;
    case QSystemTrayIcon::Warning:
        notificationIcon = QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MessageBoxWarning);
        break;
    case QSystemTrayIcon::Critical:
        notificationIcon = QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MessageBoxCritical);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    qpa_sys->showMessage(message, title, notificationIcon,
                     static_cast<QPlatformSystemTrayIcon::MessageIcon>(icon), msecs);
}
```

Now, it seems, that I need to re-implement these two functions in two classes and i'm ready to go, but.. It seems that QSystemTrayIcon is closely tied to QSystemTrayIconPrivate. Instance of QSystemTrayIconPrivate is created only in QSystemTrayIcon constructor (which I can't really change if I plan to create classes that inherit both QSystemTrayIcon and QSystemTrayIconPrivate and re-implement showMessage functions):

```
QSystemTrayIcon::QSystemTrayIcon(QObject *parent)
: QObject(*new QSystemTrayIconPrivate(), parent)
{
}

QSystemTrayIcon::QSystemTrayIcon(const QIcon &icon, QObject *parent)
: QObject(*new QSystemTrayIconPrivate(), parent)
{
    setIcon(icon);
}
```

So is there anything I am missing? Or is there another way to simply show notification message with custom icon?

Comment: [`void QSystemTrayIcon::showMessage(const QString &title, const QString &message, const QIcon &icon, int millisecondsTimeoutHint = 10000)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#showMessage-1) was added in Qt 5.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could try (not sure if it will work for system tray) is do the same as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050869/extend-qt-standard-icons) answer and override the `SP_MessageBoxWarning` / `SP_MessageBoxCritical` / `SP_MessageBoxInformation` icons, but as I said I'm not sure if the system tray just uses a downscaled version of the message box icons or if the system tray icons are separate. In the case of the latter, I guess you will have to patch QT sources, maybe add a new item to the `QSystemTrayIcon` and patch the switch to call some function provided by you to return the needed icon. Something like:

```
void QSystemTrayIconPrivate::showMessage_sys(const QString &message,
                                             const QString &title,
                                             QSystemTrayIcon::MessageIcon icon,
                                             int msecs)
{
    if (!qpa_sys)
        return;

    QIcon notificationIcon;
    switch (icon) {
    case QSystemTrayIcon::Information:
        notificationIcon = QApplication::style()-   >standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MessageBoxInformation);
        break;
    case QSystemTrayIcon::Warning:
        notificationIcon = QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MessageBoxWarning);
        break;
    case QSystemTrayIcon::Critical:
        notificationIcon = QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MessageBoxCritical);
        break;
    case QSystemTrayIcon::Custom:
        // Call a function that will fetch the needed icon and assign it to notificationIcon
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    qpa_sys->showMessage(message, title, notificationIcon,
                     static_cast<QPlatformSystemTrayIcon::MessageIcon>(icon), msecs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i understand what i have to change to make function with custom QIcon. The whole question is - how to make it without changing Qt's sources. Right now i'm thinking about inheriting QSystemTrayIcon (MyTrayIcon for example ) and completely re-implementing QSystemTrayIconPrivate (make a copy of it with MyTrayIconPrivate for example) and trying to make them work somehow with new extra function in both classes. But i'm fighting with Q_D and all of Qt's D-pointer system - https://wiki.qt.io/D-Pointer

Comment: @Shf did you check the link to the other question? If that works you do not have to patch the sources. The only question with that is if the icons overrided there are the same that are used for system tray.

Comment: Thanks, i think, that is exactly what i need. Will try this out right away

Comment: Tried to use `QProxyStyle` approach, and set to `SP_MessageBoxInformation` , but control never reaches out to `standardIcon`

 `QIcon standardIcon(StandardPixmap standardIcon, const QStyleOption *option = 0, const QWidget *widget = 0) const
    {
        // control never gets this far 
        if (standardIcon == QStyle::SP_MessageBoxInformation)
        {
            return QIcon("myicon"); 
        }
        
    }`

Comment: @Shf did you apply the style to your widget as shown in the answer? If so then I guess QT sadly just does not allow customization of that icon.

Comment: I did.. it works anywhere, BUT QSystemTrayIcon... I invoked the same line, as it calls in `QSystemTrayIconPrivate::showMessage_sys` -  `notificationIcon = QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MessageBoxInformation);` and i was in breakpoint in QStyleProxy implementation. But for QSystemTrayIcon i do not receive control. The difficult thing is that i cannot really follow through debug to see what is going on, because we use qt as dll and they may not be standard ones.. Maybe some other function is called, like QBaloonTip..

Comment: @Shf, I don't get it, from the code you posted it should go through that control, maybe for some reason the style it retrieves is not the right one. Can you just for an experiments sake try calling `QApplication::setStyle` with your custom style?

Comment: Yes, i did setStyle on my QApplication instance. And if a few places, where i tried for test run this line, the same as in QSystemTrayIconPrivate - `QIcon notificationIcon = QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MessageBoxInformation);`  I DO get the result i expect - ergo - my icon and not standard one. But i do not receive the same result in QSystemTrayIcon. It seems, that it may be part of the things, that QProxyStyle cannot change - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html#details

Comment: Warning: The common styles provided by Qt will respect this hint, because they call QStyle::proxy(), but there is no guarantee that QStyle::proxy() will be called for user defined or system controlled styles. It would not work on a Mac, for example, where menus are handled by the operating system.

Comment: @Shf sad to hear that:( Are you on Mac?

Comment: i'm on Win 7 , 64 bits, using MS VS

Comment: @Shf oh ok. I can't figure it out, from the code it seems that it should work:(

Comment: Well, QProxyStyle do informs us that there are classes, that cannot be changed via it, more system-related stuff. It seems, unfortunately, that QSystemTrayIcon is one of them.. Really don't understand, why digia decided to constraint user to standard only icons for notifications, they look so ugly (on win especially)

Comment: @Shf I know this beats the purpouse of Qt, but at least for Windows you could do a manual override with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159(v=vs.85).aspx, but I guess patching Qt sources is a better way to go.

Comment: yeaah... i guess i'll start pushing for patching sources rather.. after this investigation it seems, that all other alternatives are even worse.. Thanks for your help though